# How can a layperson acquire evidence of a past flight's gate departure and arrival times without the airline?

Tags: flight-status

Suppose that a layperson no longer trusts an airline or the airline refuses to supply such details of time. How can she cost-effectively obtain trustworthy  evidence of such times?

Answer (score 7):

If it was recent, FlightAware is useful. Here's an example for [AC 31 YYZ-PEK](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/ACA31/history). I have been on delayed flights and FlightAware showed the delays. Older flights are apparently available for a fee.

As a preventative measure, sign up for email notifications for all your flghts, You will get emails (which you can keep) when the fight gets a gate, is delayed, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The airlines don't lie.  In your case, they can't.

- Take-off and landing data is generated and supplied by the FAA/NAVC etc. [ASDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Situation_Display_to_Industry)
- Departure and Arrival data, which provided by the airline, is entirely automated.  Faking it is not worth the effort and would be immediately noticeable to consumers, such as the airport.
- Departure and Arrival times are reported to various authorities, such as the [Department of Transportation](https://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/subject_areas/airline_information/accounting_and_reporting_directives/technical_directive_15.html) so the the legal liability of 'lying' is far greater than any benefit derived by lying to a traveler.
- You also need to be specific about which Departure and/or Arrival.  Flight closing, door closing, pushback, gate arrival, door open, customs clearence are all different and not necessarily aligned or within the airlines control.

Your independent third party is the DOT...whether you trust them is up to you. :)

Publicly available sources are:

[Flight Stats](https://www.flightstats.com/go/home.do)

[Flight Aware](http://flightaware.com/)