# How can a layperson investigate the duration of a flight's delay?

Tags: legal

Suppose that a layperson doubts the duration of delay alleged by an airline. After the flight, how can she check it independently for a delay, without and before any lawsuit?

Comment: Start a stopwatch?

Comment: For most major airlines, I believe departure and arrival times are recorded automatically, as the airline and the airport operator use those logs for their own operations and planning.

Comment: People are voting to close "because it's related to law." This isn't a legal question: it's a question about finding out how late a flight was. What one _does_ with that information is likely a legal question but that's not what's being asked, here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a layperson acquire evidence of a past flight's gate departure and arrival times without the airline?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105857/how-can-a-layperson-acquire-evidence-of-a-past-flights-gate-departure-and-arriv)

Answer (score 2):

This scenario has already been addressed here: [The airlines don't lie. In your case, they can't....](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105857/how-can-a-layperson-acquire-evidence-of-a-past-flights-gate-departure-and-arriv/105884#105884)

[Flight Stats](https://www.flightstats.com/go/home.do) & [Flight Aware](http://flightaware.com/) show ~30 days history on the free side.  Longer with a subscription.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect. They do lie, and I don’t understand how they get away with it. I have alone this year sat multiple times inside the airplane, at the gate, with the door open, and have seen online the airline, the airport, and FlightAware reporting the flight as ‘left gate’. The same for arrival - often we are still taxiing when they report us all three ‘at gate’. Also, sometimes an hour later, the listed ‘arrival’ time suddenly hops back 10 or 15 minutes to a time were I was still in the air. It’s all bullshit to make the airline’s statistics look better than the competition.

Comment: @Aganju Sorry, it's is 100% correct.  There's too many difference clocks to describe publicly so 'left gate' should not be taken literally in all cases.  Keep in mind, arrival times are estimated until it can actually happen.  If you can *prove* a discrepancy >15 min, please report it to the DOT.